# Append to table instead of <li> with fineUploader

Tags: javascript, html, fine-uploader

Basically, the jQuery plugin i'm using is : http://fineuploader.com/

My HTML Mockup for the uploader template is as follows

```
<div class="span9">
      <h2>Upload file</h2>
      <div id="bootstrapped-fine-uploader">
        <noscript>
                <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
        </noscript>
       </div>
</div>
<div class="span9" style="padding-top:50px;">
       <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Filename</th>
                        <th>Filesize</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                      <tr>
                         <td colspan="3">No active uploads</td>
                      </tr>
                 </tbody>
       </table>
</div>
```

What i want to be able to do is add the **file list** on a seperate table row instead of the default which is some kind of alert, the mockup they use for this is

```
    template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
        ((!this._options.dragAndDrop || !this._options.dragAndDrop.disableDefaultDropzone) ? '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></div>' : '') +
        (!this._options.button ? '<div class="qq-upload-button"><div>{uploadButtonText}</div></div>' : '') +
        '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
        (!this._options.listElement ? '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' : '') +
        '</div>',

    // template for one item in file list
    fileTemplate: '<li>' +
        '<div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
        '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
        '<span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
        '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
        '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
        '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
        '<a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
        '<a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a>' +
        '<span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
        '</li>',
```

I actually have no idea how they call this function, although if someone with experience in this application could point me in the right direction on how i can achieve my request, i'd be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to contribute an alternate version of the `fileTemplate` option with your desired markup.  You will also need to set the `listElement` option to point to the container for your file items.  Currently, the file list is a set of list items contained in an unordered list.  You will need to set the `listElement` as your `<tbody>` with each file item (represented by the `fileTemplate` option) being a `<tr>`.

Styling the uploader in FineUploader mode is described more in the [styling Fine Uploader](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/styling.html) document.  Another option is to use [FineUploaderBasic mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/modes/fineuploaderbasic.html), which still handles cross-browser uploading for you but allows you to easily define your own UI.